# Cannot chocolatey distribution

Tags: chocolatey

I met some problem in choco.
when i input choco upgrade all
it has lots of errors.
And I have not met this thing in the past.

> ```
> This is try 1/3. Retrying after 300 milliseconds.
>  Error converted to warning:
>  对路径“C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install\.chocolateyPending”的访问被拒绝。
> This is try 2/3. Retrying after 400 milliseconds.
>  Error converted to warning:
>  对路径“C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.install\.chocolateyPending”的访问被拒绝。
> Maximum tries of 3 reached. Throwing error.
> ```

request was refuse.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging `的访问被拒绝` into Google Translate says that means "Access Denied" in English. Please correct me if that is wrong, but that probably means you aren't running `choco upgrade all` from an elevated (administrative) PowerShell session or Command Prompt.

Even if you're an admin, if you have UAC enabled you need to elevate your processes as processes start without admin privileges by default.